# Use of ASP.Net MVC while using WebAPI and completely clientside pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

We are building a completely client side application where the data comes from REST APIs delivered via ASP.Net WebAPI. For the client side application does it still make sense to go with MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are still advantages to using MVC even for a [single page application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) (SPA). Some advantages are the built-in authentication/authorization, routing, more flexibility in how you render the initial page, eliminates cross domain issues with AJAX if Web API and MVC are in the same project, and more.

Someone that knows a lot about SPA and ASP.NET MVC is John Papa.  Check out one of his [blog posts on a new VS template that is available for SPA](http://www.johnpapa.net/insidespatemplate/). John Papa has a lot of useful tips on developing SPA's with ASP.NET MVC on his blog and he has a [great training course on Pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=spa&highlight=john-papa_spa-m6-basics%2a1#spa-m6-basics).  And yes, he uses MVC with Web API.  They were designed to be used together.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I agree. MVC sold me on routing and rendering initial page. Though the framework is a overkill for a pure play javascript and html5 pages, code structure and extensiblity in future from SPA to multiple pages would be taken care by the framework easily.

Answer (score 1):

First of all let's remember the purpose of ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web API. The main purpose of ASP.NET MVC provide you with a ready to use HTML. On the other hand ASP.NET Web API main purpose is to provide you with a data.

So, in my opinion, you can use both ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web API in the case when you:

1. Have a ready to use complex ASP.NET MVC controls and want to reuse its.
2. Have a complex logic for handling some data, so that for a performance issue it would be better to handle it on the server side.
3. You have to use some specific server based ASP.NET functionality like Http Handlers, File Uploading etc.

Comment: Agreed.. Makes sense keeping future enhancements to the app in mind. Sold :)

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you don't need MVC. Sounds like you want to create a Single Page Application. All you need is an index.html to load your app.js and off you go.

MVC does not add any extra value.

Even when it comes to complex scenarios, you can create more advanced Web Api methods to service your application. You are not contained to the basic CRUD WebApi methods you get out of the box.

You can even put things like ActionFilters and DelegatingHandlers around api controllers for handling errors, metadata and all sorts of things.

Comment: My initial thoughts exactly. Extending APIs to do the most laundry tasks and UI being just a face to it makes perfect sense. Like I mentioned above, code structure and keeping future application extensibility, sticking to MVC. Else, exactly my thoughts :)